# How to allow an application in Mountain Lion in the "Security and Privacy" settings?

Tags: privacy, applescript, alfred

Every time I was trying to use an Alfred workflow written in Applescript, I got the error "No user interaction allowed".

In Mavericks there is an "Accessibility" option in the "Security and Privacy" preferences pane. Not in OS X Mountain Lion.

[image]

Is there a way, I can allow one app (ie. Alfred) in Mountain Lion?

PS: I have allowed apps downloaded from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag an applicaton to the list:

[image]

Edit: Mountain Lion has a single setting for enabling access for assistive devices for all applications:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I do not think I can drag and drop any application as there is no "Accessibility" option in OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: Absolutely. I checked it. I hope I will solve my problem by upgrading to Mavericks this week-end ;-)